# How do I back up and restore my Delphi settings?

Tags: delphi, backup, delphi-xe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate Delphi or clone Delphi registry settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140013/how-to-migrate-delphi-or-clone-delphi-registry-settings)

I need to format my PC soon, but I have the IDE and environment settings perfectly set up to just how I want them, along with some components I have installed.

Obviously formatting and reinstalling Windows will wipe all settings and registry entries, so when I do install Delphi again I will have to tweak it all to get it to how it originally was, which will take quite a bit of time that I would rather not use up.

What is the best way to retain Delphi IDE and environment settings and installed components?

Is it just a case of backing up registry entries and user data folders?

Comment: Yes - I also use VMware to avoid this exact problem.  I have a 'Dell Optiplex' minimized on this box now - fine for legacy D2-D5 stuff.  The thought of migrating all those 3rd-party components with lost licences from long-dead vendors is frightening..

Comment: I avoid the problem Martin has by never ever ever using binary-only third party components.  All my code builds from one batch file, source code and all. And I'm not stuck using a 1998 compiler. And I don't reinstall components using installers. I grab a repository and build it all, with one batch file.  Reinstalling the packages so you can open DFMs and edit them, is still too much work though.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29518422/303101 . It says: The tool for this is now built into Delphi XE8.

It's found here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\migrationtool.exe

Online documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Settings_Migration_Tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to make a complete backup of delphi XE manually:

- backup complete installation folder. 
  (tip: install your components under the delphi folder so they also get backed up).
- export & backup HKLM\Software\Embarcadero registry key
  in case of 64 bit os it will be HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Embarcadero
- export & backup HKCU\Software\Embarcadero registry key
- Some components may write BPL files to your system folder (check C:\Windows\System32 or C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder)

**after OS reinstallation:**

- reinstall Delphi to the SAME folder and apply same updates
- overwrite installation with your backup
- reimport registry keys from backup
- if you have Delphi plugins/experts, reinstall them

some tips:

- install Delphi under the root of your drive (eg c:\DelphiXE), this to prevent troubles with UAC under vista/W7.
- Keep your projects under the delphi folder, is very handy if you have to cope with different delphi versions (eg c:\delphi5\projects, c:\delphixe\projects, ...)
- make an automated daily backup of your delphi folder (via windows backup or other tool)

Comment: You can alternatively install Delphi in the regular folder in Program Files and just modify it's security properties. Both the root of your boot drive and Program Files have less-than-full-access permissions.  I am not aware of UAC having anything to do with it, but then, I always turn UAC completely off.

Comment: Whatever approach you take, the problem is that usually, components nd plugins are not all in one subdirectory of the Delphi installation. Finding and backing up all of them can be quite a task. Some of them might also have files in other directories or system directories or entries in the registry. ISTM that it is better to install everything anew.

Comment: Thats why I install all my components under the appropriate delphi directory (I Have 4 different versions on my laptop)

Comment: @WarrenP, I wish you could downvote comments without flagging them. :-) Turning UAC off as a developer is 100% the wrong thing to do. You don't get to test your app as an actual user probably would, and therefore you don't have a reason to do things the right way. I leave UAC on and just run the IDE as administrator so the debugger works, and can then run my app outside the IDE as a non-admin and test how it works.

Comment: @KenWhite +1, this is actually a good point you make. I personally always disable UAC (it can get annoying using Windows with it enabled). But I think from now when I want to debug my programs I will turn UAC back on so I can get an idea what might pop up to anyone else that may use my program.

Comment: IMHO setting UAC to 1 position lower than default and you will find it is not so annoying... As a developer you need to take into account that your programs will run under more restrictive conditions.

Comment: @whosrdaddy very true, this is something I have completely overlooked as I personally disable UAC and probably forgot all about it.

Comment: @KenWhite - I personally only lower the settings for the UAC, I don't disable it completely. HOWEVER, I don't think this is a biggie. If you know what you are doing (don't download software from strange websites) there is nothing to worry about. Until Windows 7 we all lived without UAC. We are still here. Nobody died! I think you are treating your UAC as an antivirus or something.... :) UAC is only a minimal protection.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25: Except you don't get to properly test your app from the standpoint of a normal (non-admin, full UAC enabled) user in order to make sure it works properly. UAC enabled is what the average user of Windows will experience, and if you're not having the same experience you can't be sure your software works properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try CnWizard Backup/Restore tool. If you keep same path for components and delphi install, just make backup, install delphi and cnwizard, copy all components folders and make restore.
I only have problem when migrate from XP to W764b, must to manualy change path in registry for Program Files folder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with @Martin, VMWare is great for this [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com). Not only for Delphi and its settings and component, but the whole O/S, including SPs, KBs, drivers, settings, applications & their settings, Anti virus, Firewalls.

This is what I do with VMWare ver 5 (other/newwer version might be different)

1. Install VMWare on the Host O/S. The host can be a Windows O/S or a Linux O/S variant. I personally like to use Linux as the host O/S, because, for me, the security is better towards virus, malware etc.
2. Install a guest O/S. This can be any supported O/S of choice, including any SPs, drivers needed.
3. Install Delphi and all components you need.
4. You can backup the guest O/S to a media, DVD-R, for example. If anything major happened, you can just restore it for less than 30 minutes. This is a huge benefit.

You can have as many as guest O/Ses you want (If you have the space). This is great for testing purposes. How many times you hear that your app is breaking on a particular O/S, with a specific SPs/KBs, dll or other specific settings on client PCs? With multiple guest O/Ses, you can test your app with different O/S and/or settings without having to have multiple PCs or multiple partitions with different O/Ses.

Of course VMWare has many other usages, but for me, the above usage scenario is enough.

Other Virtual Machine is from Oracle (Oracle VM) which is free [Oracle VM](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/oraclevm/index.html). They claimed to be better than VMWare, but I myself have not tested it.

Comment: One place where VM development doesn't work for me is where I need the full performance of my native system.  I experience a 2x to 5x slower operation inside the VM versus outside, while developing in  Delphi. I have delphi and all my tools both inside and outside a VM, and I use each for when it makes sense to do so for me. YMMV.