# Error creating forms in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi

I recently bought a lap-top using Windows 7, and I copied my Delphi folder to it from my old desk-top computer, which uses Windows XP.  The folder includes the Delphi 5 Standard program and the programs I have written with it, including all their source files.

I can now edit the units, but I cannot view or edit the forms.
If I call up a unit and press F12 to view its form, nothing happens. 
If I press F11 to view the Object Inspector, a blank Object Inspector appears. 
If I press Shift-F12 or click on the "View Form" icon and select a form for viewing, I get a message saying "Error Reading Form" and "Class TImage not found", or "Class TButton not found", or some other class not found, followed (when I press "Cancel") by "Error creating form. Class TImage [etc.] not found".

When I try to run a program from the IDE, I get a series of "Error Reading Form" and "Error Creating Form" messages, or (on one occasion) a message saying "[Fatal Error] FILENAME.DPR[1]. File not found: 'System.pas'"  But the compiled programs run perfectly when opened in Explorer.  [I cannot find a systems.pas file in either computer, but there is an mmsystem.pas file in Delphi's rtl\win sub-folder. Is that it?]

The units use StdCtrls. I have repeatedly re-compiled and rebuilt the programs, to no avail.

As far as I can see (but I may well be wrong), there is no error in the Environment options listed under "Tools", namely the library path (with the lib, bin, and imports sub-folders), the BPL and DCP output directories (with projects*.bpl in both), and the browsing path (with the source\vcl, ctl\sys, and rtl\win sub-folders).  I have tried replacing entries like "$(DELPHI5)\Projects\Bpl"  with "c:Program Files (x86)\borland\delphi5\projects*.Bpl, but this made no difference.

Is there a solution (preferably a simple one)?

Comment: You just copied the folders and did not ex/import the registry keys, ,bpl etc.? Then may installing will be the easiest option.

Comment: Maybe this answer can offer some help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11028045/800214

Comment: Before installing Delphi 5 be sure to go to to computer properties, to the environment variables and to set your TEMP and TMP variables to some short no-spaces path like "c:\temp" and be sure to give enough access grants to that folder. D5 installer came out before Win2000 and it is wobby on usual today long complex paths to temp storage. You can undo this AFTER installer finished and after you applied all update packs.  I also suggest you to install CdeTyphon and start working in it. Delphi 5 was a gem, but too much time went from 1999.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install Delphi using the installation program. It's not enough just to copy the installation folder. There are registry settings too. You may be able to hack together a working solution by transferring registry settings from one machine to another, but the correct solution is to install properly.

Comment: Also on Windows Vista and higher, it's very highly recommended to install into somewhere else than under `C:\Program Files`

Comment: @StijnSanders , that is if you are running with UAC, otherwise it won't make a difference. And even if you are running with UAC you can still install/run it just fine, you'll just have to run it as admin always.

Comment: Or stick a permissive ACL on Program Files/Borland

Comment: And BPLs that get put in various locations outside the Delphi folder (like the `System32` folder, for instance), and `PATH` and other environmental settings (D5, IIRC, didn't have the `Environmental Variables` stuff as part of the project configurations), and the things that get put in your user folders that the IDE needs to be able to locate.

Comment: I have followed the advice( from @David Heffernan and others), and installed Delphi 5 using the instrallation program and am running it as Administrator.

I can now run programs from the IDE. But I still cannot view or edit the forms. I get "Error Reading Form" and "Class TImage not found" (or Class TButton or some other class, not found), and then"Error creating form" 

Also, when I click on View/Component List, only one component (Frames) is shown.

What now?  Where is the apparently inaccessible information on classes and components stored?

Comment: The solution turned out to be simple. I uninstalled Belphiephi 5

Comment: The solution turned out to be simple. I uninstalled Delphi5, deleted all Delphi files, and reinstalled Delphi, and all is now well.

Comment: That's pretty much what I said!