# Delphi - Can I copy BPL between computers/systems?

Tags: delphi

I had an install of Delphi 2010 on Win7.  I had approx 20 different small VCLs which I compiled into a common BPL called MISC.BPL.     I reformatted my HDD, installed Win8 and did a new install of Delphi, same version.  Instead of having to reinstall all of these components again, is it possible to just:

1). Copy the old directory structure to the new computer (from my old backup).

2).  Copy the MISC.BPL from the old system to the new system.

3).  Update the library paths.

Will this work?  Is this close to working?  Do I have to just bite the bullet and reinstall everything?

Thanks
GS

Comment: I think you're talking about copying the installed third-party components from one machine into a new install of Delphi on a new machine ("reinstall all of these components"). If that's the case, the answer is no, you can't just copy the BPL, but [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145246).

Comment: Unfortunately, that would mean RESTORING my old system to run the cnpack utilities instead of just copying a file or two.  Looks like I will have to reinstall...  Thanks though

Comment: For the next time you may try to prepare also a backup e.g. with [`Lazy Delphi Builder`](http://www.lazyproject.info/).

Comment: For what it is worth, VCL means Visual Component Library. You do not have 20 VCLs. There is one VCL. You have 20 VCL components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BPL is just a DLL with compiled code in it.  You need it to run your compiled apps if they use Runtime Packages.  But to compile projects, you will have to actually re-install your components into the IDE as needed, and that requires more than just the BPL file by itself.