# How to copy Delphi IDE configuration to other machine?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-2006

I need to use Delphi 20006 and XE7 on my home computer, my work computer and my notebook, but I have so many components installed that keeping everything equal on those 3 devices is too difficult. I decided to use VMBox but it makes things very slow and unstable. Is there a tools or specific ordered procedures to copy those configs and keep everything in sync?

Comment: You could use git for that purpose and whenever something was changed, pull and import.

Comment: [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) has IDE Config Backup/Restore Tool

Comment: Revision control is the way to do this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Revision Control? In Delphi IDE? I thought it was meant only for the projects, and not for the IDE configuration itself. That would be great.

Comment: @SimaWB Thank you, that's what I am looking for if it can backup components and packages configuration. You could turn that into an answer.

Comment: I mean that you put the source code of your components in revision control. Or perhaps you aren't actually asking about the components.

Comment: Not mine components, but all IDE configuration, including paths and 3rd party component packs.

Comment: Delphi 2006 has many compatibility issues in Windows 8

Comment: Theres no simple way to do it. If you need just the configurations, CNPack can do it for you, otherwise, you need SNV, Git + Final Builder to assemble the environment.

Comment: I think the question has become a little confused. I don't really know quite what you are asking. There are no issues running D2006 on Windows 8.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145246/62576

Comment: @EASI: The only way is to install Delphi into the same folder, copy components and then copy registry. If you are familiar with registry, it is not that difficult but it needs some experience to find out what needs to be copied.

Answer (score 4):

[CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) has IDE Config Backup/Restore Tool, usefull wizards, plugins and components. Also it's free ;)

Comment: I tried it now. Unfortunately, it does not save config of components installed. :-(