# Is it possible to move an entire Delphi development environment?

Tags: windows, delphi, upgrade, delphi-2010, vcl

I'm working with an old (Delphi 2010) app with a number of very specific components that have to be installed, some from compiled from sources. It's a pain to set up, is what I'm getting at.

Currently, I have it on a Windows 10 machine, but I haven't upgraded Windows 10 in quite some time. If I upgrade Windows, it breaks the debugger (and I haven't been able to fix that so I've downgraded Windows).

I'm trying to find any way to move the Delphi environment without having to go through the various steps to get it to work, like making a VM out of it. Or, if I have to go through the steps again, only do it one more time in such a way that I can push-button recreate it. (There are a lot of things I need to try to upgrade the app itself, but many of those strategies will break the environment for me.)

Any strategies?

Comment: I've been through about every version of Windows, every release, and never had anything in Delphi break as a result. Your problem must be in your code. But to answer your question, yes, it is possible.

Comment: The anniversary release of Windows 10 (I think it's from fall of 2017 or maybe even 2016), when installed on my machine causes the Delphi 2010 debugger to give a "BORDBK dll failed to load" message (which is a well known issue for a variety of reasons but is not fixed by any of the proposed solutions that I have tried). When rolled back the error goes away, so I do believe there's a Delphi issue. There may be one of the hundreds of combinations of Delphi/Windows you may have missed.

Comment: By the way, Jerry, if you have ANY hint on how a developer's code could cause the BORDBK load failure, I'd be happy to learn it because, honestly, I had not considered that possibility.

Comment: You didn't mention any of that in your question. Don't just assume that I know what you've done. That's another issue I've never faced, even with that exact update, on two different machines. You should look into http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options

Comment: I re-read your question, and it looks like you're rather looking to move to a completely different machine, not just a separate environment. In that case, Embarcadero provides an IDE migration tool. But it doesn't move 100% of your environment. Any third-party libraries will need to be re-installed by you.

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem. The 3rd party libraries are killing me.

Comment: Those libraries, you have no choice but to go through their install process. Some libraries try to make it "easy" by providing an installer. But many of those actually make it harder.

Comment: If you need a particular environment that uses specific component versions and doesn't break on OS updates, creating a VM is exactly what you should be doing. And then create a backup of it that you can restore and make copies of as needed.

Comment: The problem with Windows 10 update is that it is also capable of removing old DLL files for which system determines that they are no longer needed. So it is Quite possible that during Windows update some of the DLL files that are needed for Delphi might have been removed. You could probably fix this by running the Delphi installer and chosing repair function. Using such approach should keep instalation of all of your 3rd party components.

Comment: @RemyLebeau advice of a VM is the more sensitive one. And you could use Windows 10 in the VM for free, if you can afford not to be able to customize the WallPaper... https://www.howtogeek.com/244678/you-dont-need-a-product-key-to-install-and-use-windows-10/

Comment: @Jerry:*Those libraries, you have no choice* is not true. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145246/62576). I use that technique every few years when my work computer is replaced, and it has worked every single time without re-running any third-party installations. (Copying them to the same locations avoids any path-related issues, and the registry export/import takes care of any registry settings.) A couple have required slightly more work (an addition to the Windows path, for instance), but that's fairly easy to resolve.

Comment: I will get back to everyone on this, thanks for the feedback.